# Second drop down in HTML is not getting selected through VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

My VBA code is not able to select the second drop down option once the first drop down is selected. Not sure why one dropdown is loading and second is not responding as per below code? Appreciate if you could help on fixing this. Regards

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Dim commodityStr As String
Dim commodityObj As HTMLObjectElement
Dim commodityCodes As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim codeCounter As Long
Dim EDateStr As String
Dim EDateObj As HTMLObjectElement
Dim EdateCodes As IHTMLElementCollection

Dim i As Integer




commodityStr = "MADHYA PRADESH"
EDateStr = "REWA"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/(S(ryta1dvaec5pg03bdnxa5545))/DistrictRaifall.aspx"
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
End With

Set commodityObj = HTMLDoc.getElementById("listItems")


For codeCounter = 0 To commodityObj.Length - 1
    If commodityObj(codeCounter).innerText = commodityStr Then
        commodityObj.Value = commodityObj(codeCounter).Value


           commodityObj.Focus
           commodityObj.FireEvent ("onchange")
            While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
       Exit For
 End If
 Next



Set EDateObj = HTMLDoc.getElementById("DistrictDropDownList")


For codeCounter = 0 To EDateObj.Length - 1
    If EDateObj(codeCounter).innerText = EDateStr Then
       EDateObj.Value = EDateObj(codeCounter).Value
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
commodityObj.Focus
commodityObj.FireEvent ("onchange")
     Exit For
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a timed loop to allow for that execution of the onchange event. Also, you can make use of css attribute = value selectors to remove loops when targeting elements. It is likely the page does an XHR request so inspect via dev tools to see if that is the case.

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ele As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim commodity As String, iDate As String

    commodity = "MADHYA PRADESH"
    iDate = "REWA"

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://hydro.imd.gov.in/hydrometweb/(S(3qitcijd521egpzhwqq3jk55))/DistrictRaifall.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("[value='" & commodity & "']").Selected = True
        .document.querySelector("[name=listItems]").FireEvent "onchange"
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.querySelector("[value='" & iDate & "']")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If Not ele Is Nothing Then
            ele.Selected = True
            .document.querySelector("#GoBtn").Click
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Excellent QHarr! Thanks a lot for your efforts in helping in fixing this.

Comment: But my ultimate goal of this coding is to not to target any specific elements. But to run the loops and extract data of all elements into Excel form. If you could help me looping of it would be of great help!. Thanks a lot again for your time and efforts.

Comment: Put your variables in arrays for example and loop assigning to idate and commodity in those loops.

Comment: Thanks QHarr! That is a great input for me.